# What is the difference amplifier common mode voltage?

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential-amplifier

In some sources it is stated that v1 is directly equal to Vcommon mode voltage in difference amplifier, but isn't Common mode voltage (V1)/2 as calculated?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The equation is incorrect. The common mode rejection occurs because the inputs subtract. The amplifier gain is still Avol.

The equation should be:
$$
\left(\frac{V_1}{2}-\frac{V_1}{2}\right) A_{VOL}=0
$$

\$A_{VOL}\ne0\$

Use superposition to treat the common mode input as separate equal inputs, one that is divided by 2 to a non-inverting amplifier with a gain of 2 and one to a unity gain inverting amplifier.

When the two results combine the output voltage is zero.
$$
V_o=\frac{V_i}{2}\left(1+\frac{1k}{1k}\right)-V_i\frac{1k}{1k}
$$

> but isn't Common mode voltage (V1)/2 as calculated?

If the same voltage appears at two or more nodes it is considered a common mode voltage. It is common to all the nodes. The idea behind common mode rejection is to have those voltages equal in amplitude and phase so that a voltmeter placed from one node to the other will measure zero volts.

The inputs to an op-amp are equal only if \$A_{VOL}\$ is very high so that the difference between the inputs is zero.

Comment: thanks for your feedback @RussellH  I want to write Vout as the sum of common mode and differential modes. Thus, I can see more clearly what is Common mode and Differential mode voltage.

Comment: I want to perceive it intuitively and logically. In the last figure I added, we can see that the V1 and V2 signals (at the circuit input (just before the resistor)) are taken as the basis of both common mode and differential mode voltage. In this case, the result will be correct. If we take the direct opamp inputs as basis, according to the differential mode definition (V2-V1) *Gdm =0 and according to the Common mode definition ((V1+V2)/2)*Gcm became 0 in common mode. This is the part I don't fully understand.

Answer (score 0):

There is the input [to the circuit] common mode voltage, V1.

Separately, there is the common mode *at the input of the op-amp*, which is as you state.

Both are relevant to design and analysis, for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from seeing a differential amplifier made through another differential amplifier.  However, the first is a circuit and the second is a component of this circuit.  Here they are talking about the common-mode voltage of the circuit.

The same problem exists when we talk about input voltage, input resistance, gain, etc. of an amplifier (inverting, non-inverting, etc.) made through another amplifier (op-amp).